# How does the LaTeX `ABC` music typesetting package configure spacing with `width`

Tags: packages, package-options, music

How does the `ABC` music typesetting package configure spacing with the value passed to `width`.  The documentation says `width is the dimension best expressed as a fraction of \abcwidth`

As width is one of the only user passed parameters:

1. Is the calculation that sets up spacing between notes and number of bars per line computed by the package?
2. Or is it driven by the externally called programs such as abcm2ps and thus this is no longer a remotely TeX controlled calculation.

Comment: Actually, the documentation is incorrect; one should say `\renewcommand{\abcwidth}{\dimexpr⟨fraction ⟩\linewidth\relax}` (or any other length parameter instead of `\linewidth`) so `width=.5\abcwidth` works as well. The width value is passed to `\includegraphics`, not to `abcm2ps`.

Comment: @egreg does that mean the music spacing is calculated internally, and the graphic is scaled to the page width or user defined size? If this is the case I am an still not sure if it abcm2ps that deals with note and bar spacing or the latex package, which could still need to paramaterize the spacing and wrapping so the notes are not microscopic. A possibility the external image generator can't really plan for if I understand it correctly.

Comment: There's no way to set the width with `abcm2ps` that I know of. If you know one, then pass it as an option to `abcm2ps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the slip in the documentation (discussed later), here is how `width` works.

Giving `width=<dimen>` to an `abc` environment results in `width=<dimen>` being passed to the final `\includegraphics` command. This only scales up or down the included PDF file and has no influence whatsoever on how `abcm2ps` processes its input when producing the score.

The `options=<text>` key, instead, passes the `<text>` as command line options to `abcm2ps`; so if you want to influence the width here, you should do something like

```
options={-O= -c -w 10cm}
```

(note that `-O= -c` are the default command line options).

The default value for `width` is `\abcwidth`, that's set to `\linewidth`. However, this is not a length, so if you for example want to set the width to 80% of `\linewidth` without having to specify this in all `abc` environments, you can say

```
\renewcommand{\abcwidth}{\dimexpr.8\linewidth\relax}
```

and so you can override the default width by saying `width=.45\abcwidth` (say for placing two scores side by side). This is not necessary if `\abcwidth` has the default definition.